# How much space does ConcMarkSweepGC once collect?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

This is a GC detail log printed by **ConcMarkSweepGC**.It seems that this log doesn't tell how much space be collected in this GarbageCollection.

My current JAVA_OPTS is
`-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xloggc:/home/admin/logs/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps`

Do I really can't know how much space be collected in this GarbageCollection?

Is my **JAVA_OPTS** faulty?

Logs:

```
2016-11-28T20:19:22.937+0800: 357765.356: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1734329K(2097152K)] 1925288K(4019584K), 0.0715106 secs] [Times: user=0.24 sys=0.00, real=0.08 secs] 
2016-11-28T20:19:23.010+0800: 357765.429: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2016-11-28T20:19:23.826+0800: 357766.246: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.815/0.817 secs] [Times: user=0.95 sys=0.04, real=0.81 secs] 
2016-11-28T20:19:23.827+0800: 357766.246: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2016-11-28T20:19:23.840+0800: 357766.260: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.013/0.014 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2016-11-28T20:19:23.840+0800: 357766.260: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2016-11-28T20:19:29.079+0800: 357771.499: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 5.229/5.239 secs] [Times: user=5.63 sys=0.11, real=5.24 secs] 
2016-11-28T20:19:29.081+0800: 357771.500: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 374645 K (1922432 K)]2016-11-28T20:19:29.081+0800: 357771.501: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.2260699 secs]2016-11-28T20:19:29.307+0800: 357771.727: [weak refs processing, 0.0007908 secs]2016-11-28T20:19:29.308+0800: 357771.727: [class unloading, 0.0830640 secs]2016-11-28T20:19:29.391+0800: 357771.811: [scrub symbol table, 0.0242131 secs]2016-11-28T20:19:29.415+0800: 357771.835: [scrub string table, 0.0032310 secs][1 CMS-remark: 1734329K(2097152K)] 2108975K(4019584K), 0.3421430 secs] [Times: user=1.00 sys=0.00, real=0.34 secs] 
2016-11-28T20:19:29.424+0800: 357771.843: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2016-11-28T20:19:30.204+0800: 357772.623: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.780/0.780 secs] [Times: user=0.86 sys=0.01, real=0.78 secs] 
2016-11-28T20:19:30.204+0800: 357772.623: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2016-11-28T20:19:30.214+0800: 357772.633: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.010/0.010 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
```

Answer (score 0):

We use to add -verbose:gc along with DateStamps like below: Can u please try once and confirm.

```
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -verbose:gc
```

You can take the help from this site, as we use to refer this  : http://blog.sokolenko.me/2014/11/javavm-options-production.html

Answer (score 0):

Your JVM options are good. But CMS is working concurrently and does not print final size of old generation at end of cycle.

You need to look at **young GC** reports to see how much memory occupied in old space after CMS sweep is complete.

```
12.515: [GC (Allocation Failure) 12.515: [ParNew: 34805K->3103K(38080K), 0.0039903 secs] 134805K->103463K(122752K), 0.0040432 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
```

In line above old space usage after young GC is `103463K - 3103K = 100360K`.

You can calculate reclaimed memory size by calculating difference in old space size between last young GC before final remark and first young GC after concurrent reset.

Or you can use excellent [GCViewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer) tool to visualize your logs.

You can find more information about reading GC logs [here](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/12/garbage-collection-in-hotspot-jvm.html).

Answer (score 0):

openjdk 8: `-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC`

openjdk 9: `-Xlog:gc,heap+gc` due to the new unified logging system